# DC-DC voltage regulator circuit (LTSpice)

Tags: voltage-regulator, ltspice

Basically I want to recreate this circuit in LTSpice.

[image]

I was told that I can skip the left part of the circuit, so this is what I made.

[image]

I changed the diode, added a "custom made" potentiometer X2 and a load for the output. This is the schematic of X2.

[image]

The voltage across the load ended up being -792.4mV. Without the load the output voltage was 0 V (with respect to ground). I don't understand what's the problem with my circuit. I also don't know what output voltage I should be getting. Any suggestions? Also why is the output terminal not connected between VR2 and R4 in the original circuit?

Comment: Do you know what that section on the left does?  You can "leave it out" in the sense that LTspice has a component that does what that section does.  If you leave it out, you have to replace its function.

Comment: No I don't really know what that section does.

Comment: The left part is an "astable" with "PWM" control ...

Comment: Notice that in removing that part of the circuit you have also removed an inverter between TR2 and R2, so you'll have to duplicate that functionality as well as the astable.

Comment: It's also kind of a horrifically bad circuit for several reasons, you'd be better off using a modern buck converter/controller IC.

Comment: You mean the original circuit is bad? Why so? I'm just curious.

Comment: @kauselis3000 Some of the reasons are that it relies on the Vbe of a BJT for the reference, which will drift with temperature.  It uses a PNP transistor for switching, which is a slow device, meaning poor efficiency and low switching frequency leading to a much larger solution size, high output ripple, and probably poor transient response even though the control looks kind of hysteretic.  It may be more expensive than a modern circuit too, due to the large inductor and extra capacitance required.  That's just what occurs to me off the top of my head, it may have other problems as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something from the Roman Black website: namely [here](https://www.romanblack.com/smps/smps.htm). Just two BJTs and it's a buck (assuming that's what you want here.)

Here's a slightly modified version (and just updated for better efficiency):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faTGyS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Efficiency is over 80% according to LTspice; including the inductor parasitics.

Don't use a 1N4734A. It needs to run more than 10 times hotter than a low-current zener and seriously impairs efficiency.

*(I've also used a Zetex device. It only improves the efficiency about 1%. But 1% is another 1%.)*

Here's an LTspice run using a load that approximates the one you indicated (\$200\:\text{mA}\$.)

[image]

It's not adjustable. But that can be easily added.

Here's what the inductor is doing at its quiescent point, loaded:

[image]

Frequency is slightly less than \$5.5\:\text{kHz}\$.

A nice thing about this design is that increasing \$C_1\$ increases the time required for the output voltage to reach it's regulated value. (Making it easy to change the ramp rate is a *feature* of the design.)

The value assignments I made were taken quickly and without much analysis. Any errors are mine.

Added note per comment below question:

PWM can be used to adjust the voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDoXRF.png)</sup>

Comment: Would it be possible to make this regulator adjustable by using an Arduino connected to the base of Q1 and using it's switching properties? If so how should I show this in my schematic?

Comment: @kauselis3000 What I had in mind when I wrote my comment was close to what you are asking about. If you remove the zener entirely (cut it away from the circuit, don't short it out) and use a 0-10V PWM, via R1, then you can adjust the voltage. So that's a very easy modification. However, you do need a 2-quadrant (class-AB) driver for R1 and it needs to switch between ground and the 10 V unreg in the schematic. That was what I was considering when I wrote in my answer. There are other possibilities, but you should probably pose another question to ask for various approaches there.

Comment: @kauselis3000 I included a behavioral addition to the schematic, at bottom. That's what I mean.