# Problems controlling the Roman Black regulator using ESP32

Tags: voltage-regulator, pwm, esp32

This is post is related to my previous post about buck converters.([DC-DC voltage regulator circuit (LTSpice)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674614/dc-dc-voltage-regulator-circuit-ltspice)). Basically, I was suggested to make roman black regulator that could be controlled using PWM. So I tried to do that with the components that I had at hand. Here's the LTspice schematic of the circuit.

[image]

[image]

I assembled the circuit in real life and ran into many issues.

[image]

1. When the load was 20 ohms the inductor was overheating.
2. When I used a function generator(and later on a ESP32) to generate a square wave at 5kHz, I found that changing the duty cycle did not change the output voltage at all.
3. Instead of the ZTX751 pnp transistor which was suggested to me I used a 2SA1015. When I connected using the correct layout of the pins the output voltage was around 80mV. When I switched the collector with the emitter I got an output voltage of around 2.5 V but as stated in 1) the inductor got very hot within seconds.

I have tried changing the load (R4) and the output voltage did change but I could not adjust it using PWM. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for the inductor? What is it's current rating?

Comment: That inductor doesn't look anywhere *near* big enough for such a low switching frequency. It's probably saturating, and that's why you're getting overheating.

Comment: I'm not at my lab right now, so I'll make to ask my teacher about the axial inductor next week.

Comment: What is the 2SA1015 current rating? ZTX751? What is the diode rating? Inductor? Why is the feedback capacitance so freaking massive? (I guess I should tag @periblepsis for that last one) (also since they'll probably like to check this thread) :)

Comment: Math Keeps Me Busy's answer may solve your problem. If you are happy with the Black Regulator results then the following is not needed. || The BR often enough does not produce as good results as people have come to expect from a modern buck regulator. A usually somwhat btter result is often achieved by use of "my" GSR. [Various SE links hr](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3288+GSR) . The GSR is not as amenable to PWM variable voltage control as the GSR 0 you my need to develop a Kuselis Regulator version :-).

Comment: Interest only" The Black regulator was the result of a design challenge that I proposed in 2001. Roman Black's result was simpler than my GSR, but more problematic.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks. You've added much of interest. This should be captured somewhere. Not the conclusions: not whether one or your GSR editions or RB's version it's better... But instead what matters is the way you, Roman Black, or Richard Prosser think about the world and imagine and pursue answers given a question or problem. I'll spend some time because I expect I will learn and very much enjoy hearing the melodies or your minds singing to me. Thanks again for the links. And thanks for just being there, too. And best wishes to you. I feel a profound loss of not knowing you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modeled the circuit in your post in CircuitLab

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9AdHM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As can be seen by a simulation run, the start-up current consists of very low duty ratio spikes.

[image]
[image]

If the inductor is not adequately rated to handle this current, it will saturate, and the converter will never reach its intended operating conditions. The maximum inductor current in steady state with a 50 \$\Omega\$ load and and output voltage of about 4.6 V, is about 500 mA. But the peak inductor current at start-up is about 2.2 A!

If you choose to try to make this circuit work, be sure your inductor is capable of handling 2.2A without saturating.